# Django-cms haystack search - placeholder content

Tags: python, django, templates, django-haystack, django-cms

i have problem with results in django-cms and haystack search. I'm using django-cms-search plugin, haystack as backend. Haystack returns correct results. But i want to show "teaser" in search results.

I can access absolute URL and title of page via template this way:

```
{% for result in page.object_list %}
<div class="searchResults">
<h2>{{ result.object.get_title }}</h2>
{{ result.object.placeholders.all }}           
<p><a href="{{ result.object.get_absolute_url }}">{% blocktrans %} Read more {% endblocktrans %}</a></p>
```

Problematic part is `{{ result.object.placeholders.all }}`. I have on every page content in placeholder with name content.

`{{ result.object.placeholders.all }}` returns only name of the placeholders.

Search results should look like this:

PAGE TITLE

PAGE TEASER

READ MORE LINK

In teaser there should be first 50 words from search-matched page.

Is this possible to access placeholder content from template?

Thank you for your tips.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Haystack has templatetag higlight which creates "teaser" as i requested.

Template code can look like this:

```
{{ result.object.get_title }}
{% highlight result.text with request.GET.q max_lenght 40 %}
{{ result.object.get_absolute_url }}
```

Thanks to guys from #haystack IRC channel.