# Get Django CMS plugin information from Haystack search results

Tags: django, elasticsearch, django-haystack, django-cms

My search results page needs to display information about the Plugins where the query was found, too. I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10073189/django-cms-haystack-search-placeholder-content) with a similar problem, but I don't only need the contents, I need to know stuff about the plugin - i.e. what's it called, where it is on the page and stuff. Basically I would like a reference to the plugin where the query was located, but I can only find information about the page and title. I haven't been able to find it anywhere on the `SearchQuerySet` object and in the vicinity - also coming up empty in the documentation for Haystack. Is it possible and how?

Stack I'm using: Elasticsearch 2.4, django-haystack 2.8, aldryn-search 1.0 (for CMS indexing).

Answer (score 0):

I ended up writing a new index for CMSPlugins. Not sure how much use my code is, but maybe it'll help someone out.

```
from django.conf import settings

from aldryn_search.helpers import get_plugin_index_data
from aldryn_search.utils import clean_join, get_index_base
from cms.models import CMSPlugin


class CMSPluginIndex(get_index_base()):
    haystack_use_for_indexing = True
    index_title = True

    object_actions = ('publish', 'unpublish')

    def get_model(self):
        return CMSPlugin

    def get_index_queryset(self, language):
        return CMSPlugin.objects.select_related(
            'placeholder'
        ).prefetch_related(
            'placeholder__page_set'
        ).filter(
            placeholder__page__publisher_is_draft=False,
            language=language
        ).exclude(
            plugin_type__in=settings.HAYSTACK_EXCLUDED_PLUGINS
        ).distinct()

    def get_search_data(self, obj, language, request):
        current_page = obj.placeholder.page
        text_bits = []

        plugin_text_content = self.get_plugin_search_text(obj, request)
        text_bits.append(plugin_text_content)

        page_meta_description = current_page.get_meta_description(fallback=False, language=language)

        if page_meta_description:
            text_bits.append(page_meta_description)

        page_meta_keywords = getattr(current_page, 'get_meta_keywords', None)

        if callable(page_meta_keywords):
            text_bits.append(page_meta_keywords())

        return clean_join(' ', text_bits)

    def get_plugin_search_text(self, base_plugin, request):
        plugin_content_bits = get_plugin_index_data(base_plugin, request)
        return clean_join(' ', plugin_content_bits)

    def prepare_pub_date(self, obj):
        return obj.placeholder.page.publication_date

    def prepare_login_required(self, obj):
        return obj.placeholder.page.login_required

    def get_url(self, obj):
        parent_obj = self.ancestors_queryset(obj).first()

        if not parent_obj:
            return obj.placeholder.page.get_absolute_url()

        return # however you get the URL in your project

    def get_page_title_obj(self, obj):
        return obj.placeholder.page.title_set.get(
            publisher_is_draft=False,
            language=obj.language
        )

    def ancestors_queryset(self, obj):
        return obj.get_ancestors().filter(
            plugin_type=# Some plugins that I wanted to find
        ).order_by(
            '-depth'
        )

    def get_title(self, obj):
        parent_obj = self.ancestors_queryset(obj).first()

        if not parent_obj:
            return self.get_page_title_obj(obj).title

        return # get title from parent obj if you want to

    def prepare_site_id(self, obj):
        return obj.placeholder.page.node.site_id

    def get_description(self, obj):
        return self.get_page_title_obj(obj).meta_description or None
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using aldryn-search, you only need to define in PLACEHOLDERS_SEARCH_LIST all the placeholders you want to check, therefore all plugins inside will be checked:

```
PLACEHOLDERS_SEARCH_LIST = {
    '*': {
        'include': ['content'],
        'exclude': [''],
    },
}
```